# REg Exp allowing ASCII Printable characters, Special characters allowed, Spaces not allowed

Tags: regex

I am looking for a Regular Expression which should have `Min 1-Max 50` characters accepted and Accepts ASCII Printable characters, Special characters allowed, Spaces not allowed.

Right now I'm having

```
^[ -~][^\\s]{1,50}$
```

but when I enter one single character it throws an error. Could anyone please check with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could go with this:

```
^\S{1,50}$
```

It will take any non white space character between 1 and 50 occurrences.
In words your regex is saying: "take a character between space and "~", then take from 1 to 50 characters except any white-space. That is why it wont work with a single character, it needs at least two.

I usually go to [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for reference and testing. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex that consists of a single character class that matches ASCII symbols from an exclamation mark (since it comes right after the space. its hex code is 21) till a tilde, add the quantifier and wrap with anchors.

```
^[!-~]{1,50}$
```

The `^[ -~][^\\s]{1,50}$` regex matches the start of string, then any printable ASCII char and then any nonwhitespace char at the end of the string, thus, as you see, it cannot match a single char string.

The `^[!-~]{1,50}$` matches a string that only consists of 1 to 50 ASCII printable chars other than space.

Comment: I have no idea how that `[` appeared before `{`. Removed.